# Generating a numeric pattern in query result set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm looking to add an artificial grouping to my result set. I can't utilize `ROW_NUMBER` or `RANK`.

Take the following result from `SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM myTbl`:

```
Col1     Col2
----     ----
x        y
x        z
y        x
z        x
x        z
y        x
```

I want to add a column that will count to 3 and then repeat so I can subdivide the result set if need be:

```
Divider  Col1     Col2
-------  ----     ----
1         x        y
2         x        z
3         y        x
1         z        x
2         x        z
3         y        x
```

Of course the easy way would be to loop through the result set with a cursor or temp table and add it on, but when the result set is 4 million rows, performance will be terrible.

Anyone know how to add this Divider column directly into a `SELECT` statement?

In reality, the query will retrieve the result set ordered by date but I still want the divider to count off in a fixed manner.  If I would try to partition and use row_number the sequence would be unpredictable.  Suppose I wanted to take the larger result set and spread it out over a set of queues but I want them evenly distributed by date to make sure each queue is processing the most recent data. If I would order by date and subdivide only one of the queues would get the most recent data.

I'm not actually returning the date in the result set; I am only ordering by it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your comments you will be ordering the results by date. In that case you could use

```
ROW_Number () over( order by date)
```

Which would output the row numbers.  You could then use the [SQL Modulo function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276866(v=sql.80).aspx), % and perform a %3 which would give you 1,2,0 repeating as the row output which gives you the grouping you want.